# Effective Scala

Tags: scala

I have just started to learn Scala.
I was looking for something in line with Effective Java for Scala.

What are your thoughts, opinions, tips on writing ***Effective Scala Code?***

Comment: Josh Suereth's Scala in Depth is the closest thing you can get to "Effective Scala".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you ever need to know about Scala... [Learning Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379540/learning-scala).  The first answer is very detailed.

In particular, check this book out: http://www.artima.com/shop/programming_in_scala.

Answer (score 1):

There's [Effective Scala](http://twitter.github.com/effectivescala/) from Twitter, but I don't know how it compares. I haven't read either.